# MySQL Multiple LEFT JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

This is a MySQL codes I wrote to join **TWO** tables, and it successfully generates a new table I desire:

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM MarketingDb.ListingProduct ListingProduct
LEFT JOIN ErpDb.ProductListingDetail ProductListingDetail
ON ListingProduct.ProductListingId = ProductListingDetail.ProductId
WHERE ProductListingDetail.ComponentType = "S" 

LIMIT 10;
```

Since I actually wanna join **THREE** tables, therefore I add 2 new lines of codes to the above SQL;
the WHERE clause above is required b4 I join the 3rd table.

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM MarketingDb.ListingProduct ListingProduct
LEFT JOIN ErpDb.ProductListingDetail ProductListingDetail
ON ListingProduct.ProductListingId = ProductListingDetail.ProductId
WHERE ProductListingDetail.ComponentType = "S" 


LEFT JOIN ErpDb.Product Product
ON Product.SKU = ProductListingDetail.ProductListingId

LIMIT 10;
```

But this time it fails, and error prompt said I have SQL syntax error for the 2 new lines of codes.
Can someone kindly help me identify my error to fix the problem? Thx!

Comment: The `where` clause goes *after* the `from` clause (so, after all the `join`s).

Answer (score 1):

that because wthe Where clause has ti be after the from clause , and your joins bolng all to the FROM Section of the query

Making a `SELECT *`  can get you into troulbe, so you shiuld soecify which columns you actually need

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM MarketingDb.ListingProduct ListingProduct
LEFT JOIN ErpDb.ProductListingDetail ProductListingDetail
ON ListingProduct.ProductListingId = ProductListingDetail.ProductId
LEFT JOIN ErpDb.Product Product
ON Product.SKU = ProductListingDetail.ProductListingId
WHERE ProductListingDetail.ComponentType = "S"
LIMIT 10;
```